# GSL integration behaves strange

Tags: c++, gsl

I am doing integration over (-infty, +infty) using the gsl_integration_qagi routine. My expectation is that upon translation along the x-axis the result of integration (area under the curve) should not change. However that is not, what I observer. Am I making a mistake somewhere? The code is attached below:

The variable offset basically creates the translation. The area remains same for offset values of 0, 10.0, 20.0, (as expected) but then suddenly drop to zero after offset ~ 40.0

```
double offset=200.0;

double f (double x, void * params) {
   double alpha = *(double *) params;
   x += offset;
   double f = exp(-x*x);
   return f;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    gsl_integration_workspace * w
     = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000);

    double result, error;
    double expected = -4.0;
    double alpha = 1.0;

    gsl_function F;
    F.function = &f;
    F.params = &alpha;

    gsl_integration_qagi (&F, 0, 0.001, 1000,
                          w, &result, &error);

    printf ("result = % .18f\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I reproduced your issue and I can't think of another explanation than the fact the GSL missed the integrand due to the limited support of the function and the low order (15) guassian approximation used by qagi.

Comment: Hi, I think you are right. The problem is due to two reasons: (a) limited support as you correctly pointed out, but more importantly, (b) non-linear shrink-factor due to the x= (1-t)/t transformation, which shrinks by a factor of 1/t^2... and at t = 1000, the support will essentially looks like a narrow vertical line due to the 10^-6 shrinkage :(... I haven't yet found a good way to get rid of this problem.
my main problem is two (or more) Gaussians separated by x = 1000+ needs to be integrated... so I need something absolutely good method to take care of integrals, without too much loss

Comment: You know the approximate support of these functions, so you don't need to use qagi! Simple qag from x_median - epsilon  to x_median + epsilon where epsilon is a reasonable number will fit. Do that separately for each Gaussian and then sum the final result. There is no universal adaptive integrator that works for all cases. You need to give whatever "extra" information you have about the function to the integrator (and limiting the range of integration is a way to give this extra information)

Comment: but is an excellent numerical question . I gave a +1 vote

Comment: I completely agree, GSL is excellent and at least there is nothing that works weird or non-sensical :). In fact quadpack seems to be a universal base for almost all the existing integration libraries, so we will have to leave with it for a while, I guess.

Comment: In the practical case, the integrand is generated from the list of means and a common convolution function, and then the integration happens on this whole function. There might be 20+ such Gaussians and 100s of such series. Calling qag for every Gaussian separately will require approximately 20*100*(100-1)/2 qag calls. I am not sure if that will be a very efficient algorithm :(... but certainly worth trying! thanks!!

Comment: Don't worry. I have a program for my physics research that calls qag ~ 10000 times (with a very hard integrand which is approx ~ sin(2x)/x^2 + delta functions in particular places ). From this code experience for example, I could actually test that it is much faster to have more calls of qag in smaller ranges (it is a oscillatory function ) then allow QAG to get stuck

Comment: A good experiment: try to integrate sin(50 x) from 0 to a very large number. First: use few qag calls and large ranges ( >> 20 full cycles) vs a lot of calls of qag (each region with 5-20 full cycles ). You have to adjust a little to have the optimal choice, but I am sure it wont be the super large range with full cycles!

Comment: but if you really want a very powerful and slow integrator try CQUAD double adaptive in the new GSL 1.15/1.16 version

Comment: @ViniciusMiranda: Thanks a lot. You have been really very helpful. I will try both your suggestions and update you soon :).

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to integrate a function with very limited support using qagi and that is bad. The chances that the integration will miss entirely the integrand is large. Why?

Qagi uses the 15 point Gauss Rule. This approximatelly means that it will evaluate the function at the following fixed points (first iteration)

```
  const double center = 0.5 * (a + b);
  const double half_length = 0.5 * (b - a);
  const double abscissa = half_length * xgk[jtw];
  const double fval1 = GSL_FN_EVAL (f, center - abscissa);
  const double fval2 = GSL_FN_EVAL (f, center + abscissa);
```

where

```
  static const double xgk[8] =    /* abscissae of the 15-point kronrod rule */
  {
     0.991455371120812639206854697526329,
     0.949107912342758524526189684047851,
     0.864864423359769072789712788640926,
     0.741531185599394439863864773280788,
     0.586087235467691130294144838258730,
     0.405845151377397166906606412076961,
     0.207784955007898467600689403773245,
     0.000000000000000000000000000000000
 };
```

(this is taken directly from GSL code).  Then, depending on the values GSL get from those points, it can divide a particular region further and apply this rule again.

From the non linear transformation `x = (1-t)/t` (this is the transformation gsl applies to map [-infinity, infinity] into (0-1] interval) , we can say that x = 0 is mapped on t = 1. Furthermore, one of the points of evaluation is `t = half_length (1.0 +  0.991455371120812639206854697526329) ~ 1`. Then, the chances that integrator will miss your function when offset is zero is quite small (that is why there is no problem to integrate reasonable functions center at x=0 using qagi). However,as you translate x by an offset, you fit the entire function (which has a very limited support) between two of the 30 points of evaluation. In this case, GSL completely misses your function and returns zero.

Summary in simple words: GSL is trying to analyze the entire [-infinity, infinity] interval using only 30 points in the first iteration. The chances that it will miss a function with very limited support centered at an arbitrary x is very high!! Only use qagi if the support of your function is very large!

Comment: May I ask a dumb question? In the comments and your post you used the word "limited support." I wonder to what it refers?

Comment: support is the interval/collection of intervals where the function is nonzero.