# GSL qag_integration is terribly slow for exponential functions

Tags: c++, gsl

This question is kind of follow up to my previous question here [GSL integration behaves strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190038/gsl-integration-behaves-strange)

Because of the scaling `x -> (1-t)/t` causing undesired answers in the infinite integration method `gsl_integration_qagi` I am now resorted to using the integration over a finite support. What I now do is this:

I have a (discrete) series `S` of real numbers, which I convolute (each) with a given exponential function

```
    exp(-t/T) ... T = decay constant
```

I choose the support for integration to be `(min(S) - 10*T, max(S) + 10*T)` so that I cover most of the "significant" contribution from the function.

Integrating over this support using `gsl_integration_qag` takes over a few seconds, while gsl_integration_qagi` (infinite support) hardly a few milliseconds but produces wrong results. Does anyone know a reason?

The same `gsl_integration_qag` works well if the convolution is Gaussian instead of exponential.

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Comment: Can you post a test code so I can take a look?

Comment: And remember: the qagi was very fast because it was missing the function support entirely (so the integrator got a very fast convergence to zero).

Comment: I also think that you should integrate each S convoluted separately, because if they are separated by a significant interval - qag will have trouble to converge (two exponential separated by a large zero interval)...but I need to see your code to check